# ADFv1 to ADFv2 migration for CosmosToBlobCopyActivity

Tags: azure-data-factory, cosmos

I'm migrating some of the pipelines under ADFv1 to ADFv2.

I found one pipeline having activity as type **CosmosToBlobCopyActivity**. This is not CosmosDB, but Cosmos structure stream data.

What is the equivalent in ADFv2

```
"activities": [
        {
            "type": "CosmosToBlobCopyActivity",
            "typeProperties": {
                "EmailRecipients": "ABC@XYZ.com"
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "DS_INPUT"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "DS_OUTPUT"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "04:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                "retry": 3,
                "longRetry": 10,
                "longRetryInterval": "01:10:00"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "CosmosToBlobCopyActivity",
            "description": "Pipeline Activity: CosmosToBlobCopyActivity",
            "linkedServiceName": "DEMOLS"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure DataFactory dont have an activity type named 'CosmosToBlobCopyActivity'. This is a custom activity in ADF v1. So you need to create a custom activity in ADF v2.

You can have a look of these below doc:

This is how to create custom activity in v1:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-use-custom-activities#create-a-pipeline-with-custom-activity

This is how to create custom activity in v2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity